# How do I remove the added space with default labels on nested enumerate environments

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, nesting

I would like to remove the added space before nested `enumerate` environments, when using the default labelling system. Note that I would like to make this change globally, rather than having to do it with each environment. Here is a MWE illustrating what I would like to have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand\insertitem[1]{\item{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
This is the first enumerate, with the ``custom'' labels.
This is how I would like mt enumerate environments to look in general
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
This is my second enumerate, with the default labels.
Note the extra space between the 1. and (a).
I would like to change this globally to have the same spacing as the first enumerate environment.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried messing with `\leftmargin`, `\itemsep`, etc., with no success.

Answer (score 5):

Somehow »[enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)« does the job better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item This is the first enumerate, with the ``custom'' labels. This is how I would like mt enumerate environments to look in general
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is my second enumerate, with the default labels. Note the extra space between the 1. and (a). I would like to change this globally to have the same spacing as the first enumerate environment.
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps that's the reason why »[enumerate](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate)« is superseded by this package.

---

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the `enumerate` package? I have a very long document that I'm using enumerate for, and would have to change a lot of syntax to make it work.

Comment: @AbeSchulte: You may take a look at the [answer of Alan](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141536/1063)

Answer (score 4):

The `enumitem` package can emulate `enumerate` syntax if you load it with the `shortlabels` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newcommand\insertitem[1]{\item{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
This is the first enumerate, with the ``custom'' labels.
This is how I would like mt enumerate environments to look in general
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
This is my second enumerate, with the default labels.
Note the extra space between the 1. and (a).
I would like to change this globally to have the same spacing as the first enumerate environment.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't recommend it, if you can't switch to the `enumitem` package, you can solve your issue by adding this line to your preamble:

```
\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}
```

so that your modified MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand\insertitem[1]{\item{#1}}

\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
This is the first enumerate, with the ``custom'' labels.
This is how I would like mt enumerate environments to look in general
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
This is my second enumerate, with the default labels.
Note the extra space between the 1. and (a).
I would like to change this globally to have the same spacing as the first enumerate environment.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]